# Can I use a camp fuel butane bottle with a brazing torch?

Tags: plumbing, gas

I have a large blue butane bottle with regular attached that connects to my camping stove.

Could I, safely and practically, use this gas with a [propane brazing torch](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/192052426161)?

I want to bond steel with a brazing rod, not solder.

Comment: Propane bottles are $4.  so you are asking us to help you save $4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Butane has a much higher boiling point than propane (31 F vs. -44 F).  So if you're burning it at a fast rate, the pressure will be different.  If you're working in freezing temperatures, you may even have trouble feeding the torch.

Also, I've read that butane doesn't transfer its heat as effectively (see [this](http://juxtamorph.com/butane-versus-propane-which-is-hotter/) for example).  They have similar BTUs, but the rationale is that the butane flame is more diluted because it takes more combustion air.  I have no idea whether that's true.  That wouldn't make any difference for a camping stove, but brazing steel is more demanding.

Nozzles designed for butane are different, and a different air/fuel mix is required.  So a torch designed for propane may not give the best butane flame.  All the torches I've seen designed for butane are small, but designed to get the optimum flame from the butane.

The canister connection may also be different depending on size, but is you're asking the question, I'm guessing that issue doesn't apply..

You want to use it for a demanding application.  The only way to tell if it will be effective is to try it.  It may be good enough, but it isn't likely to be as effective with a torch designed for propane as using propane.  If it does work, you may go through a lot more butane for the job than the amount of propane that would be required.

Answer (score 1):

Will it work, yes. With the right adapters and with the right brazing torch. Is it safe? No. Is it cost effective? Also no. But you can do it.

The adapters are going to cost you $10/piece and you'll need at least 2. You'll have to grease the gaskets on the adapters with synthetic silicone grease to maintain a seal and the threads of the adapters with a similiar synthetic inert PTFE grease because these adapters are made in china out of whatever scrap metal they have lying around and sparks are very possible just screwing the thing on and off. Leaks between the adapters are very possible.

And it will ONLY work with a the most expensive propane torches, the ones with built in regulators that are map-pro compatible with flames with names like "swirl", "turbine" or "turbo torch" like the bernzomatic ts8000 or the turbo torch STK-9 because the high venturi effect and the  nozzle on these models will pressurize the butane to high enough levels on its on. A regular solid brass pencil flame propane torch will not work with butane. You will get a very small flame that will make the torch very hot and possibly blow the canister. The pressure is far too low for most propane torches.

The flame characteristics are different too. Butane in a ts8000 makes a very large cone of a flame. Hard to direct. Because of this it can't heat a single spot very well. It doesn't transfer heat the same way, and it is much harder to control and less precise than propane. The torch wasn't meant for it after all. You can get turbo torches meant for those butane camp gas canisters for less money than an adapter costs though.

What you really want is those flat isobutane camp fuels. They're usually 75% isobutane (aka methylpropane) with propane and a little butane mixed in.
That stuff burns hot and transfers heat fast. Hotter than propane, even hotter than map-pro. But it's more toxic and carcinogenic than either butane or propane if you can about that sort of thing.